# UISplitViewController presentsWithGesture not working

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I can't seem to get presentsWithGesture to work.  I need to be able to turn it on and off based on the detail view controller that is displayed.

```
- (IBAction)disableGestures:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;

    NSLog(@"Disable Gestures!");
}
```

I've put together a simple project (using the default UISplitViewController template):
http://www.filedropper.com/splitviewtest

Is this not the intended use of presentsWithGesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can only change `presentsWithGesture` in the AppDelegate.

My solution was to disable it and add a UISWipeGestureRecognizer that I could control.

Comment: presentsWithGesture should be set prior to setting delegate. So you can't disable it after the delegate be set.

Answer (score 1):

After setting `presentsWithGesture` to NO (or false), you should also disable the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` from `UINavigationController` instances in both master and detail viewcontrollers:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled = false
}
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Code for SplitView type Application

If u you want to disable the Gesture in Landscape mode then below code is use full for u

step-1 import the #AppDelegate.h in detailView.h

step-2 implement this method in detailView.h

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
          inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but as you can see in my sample code, I'm already doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the split view controller property presentsWithGesture to No by adding this code to your detail view controller (which should be a UISplitViewControllerDelegate)

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController *) svc
   shouldHideViewController: (UIViewController *) vc
              inOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation
{
   svc.presentsWithGesture = NO;

   return YES;
}
```